# "Cannot connect to server" to Bot on iPad

Tags: xcode, macos, continuous-integration, bots, osx-server

I have posted this on Ask Different, and I thought it might fit here as well.

I have a Bot running for my app, with just a regular development account. I want to be able to download the Product that is created, but when I go to the Bot web page, I get an error "Cannot connect to ". I find this a little strange, because I can hit the server web page. Any ideas? Do you have to have an enterprise account to donwload the product?

The iPad has all the correct profiles etc.